# How to use (current_dt - 7 ) function in inorder to get last 7 days from a table

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table called phonebooth and column named phone_data. I'm looking to fetch last 7 days data.
How can I use (current dt - 7) function in order to get these data in snowflake?

Comment: snowflake is *not* mysql

Comment: does this help: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/current_date.html
https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/dateadd.html

Comment: always clarify if you are talking about dates or datetimes

Comment: An answer has been provided and other questions asked. You should accept the answer, or update your question with further information.

Comment: Yeah I am using snowflake and looking for date.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're actually using Snowflake (and not MySQL as your post is tagged as well):

```
SELECT
    c1
    ,c2
FROM t1
WHERE TO_DATE(phonebooth) >= DATEADD(DAY,-7,CURRENT_DATE())
```

Or a shorter version

```
SELECT
    c1
    ,c2
FROM t1
WHERE TO_DATE(phonebooth) >= CURRENT_DATE() - 7
```

Comment: How can I add a condition which calls other column(expiration_ts) in a different table for eg 'expiration_ts = NULL'  to get all the rows.